# Mapping two sources to one output

Tags: java, xslt

I want to performs XSLT on two sources.

Sourch_1.xml:

```
<Root>
<record>
    <PolicyNumber>1</PolicyNumber>
    <FirdsName>aa</FirdsName>
    <LastName>aa</LastName>
</record>
<record>
    <PolicyNumber>2</PolicyNumber>
    <FirdsName>bb</FirdsName>
    <LastName>bb</LastName>
</record>
```

Sourch_2.xml:

```
<Root>
<record>
    <policy>
        <PolicyNumber>1</PolicyNumber>
        <city>aaCity</city>
        <street>aaStreet</street>
    </policy>
    <policy>
        <PolicyNumber>2</PolicyNumber>
        <city>bbCity</city>
        <street>bbStreet</street>
    </policy>
</record>
```

I want the output to create  tags which combine data from two sources based on PolicyNumber.

I want my output to be:

output.xml:

```
<Root>
<record_data>
    <PolicyNumber>1</PolicyNumber>
    <FirdsName>aa</FirdsName>
    <LastName>aa</LastName>
    <city>aaCity</city>
    <street>aaStreet</street>
</record_data>
<record_data>
    <PolicyNumber>2</PolicyNumber>
    <FirdsName>bb</FirdsName>
    <LastName>bb</LastName>
    <city>bbCity</city>
    <street>bbStreet</street>
</record_data>
```

How can i accomplish that using XSLT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To process more than one XML input file, use the `document()` function. Make sure that additional XML files are in the folder where you put the XSLT stylesheet, too.

The line that deserves your attention is the following:

```
<xsl:for-each select="document('double2.xml')/root/record/policy[./PolicyNumber=current()/PolicyNumber]">
```

To begin with, `document('double2.xml')` opens the second XML file (I have dubbed it "double2.xml"). For the `policy` elements in this second XML file it checks whether their `PolicyNumber` is equal to the `PolicyNumber` of the `record` element from the first XML file that is being processed

---

I have slightly modified your input to make it well-formed (lowercased the `root` element and added its closing tag). Note that there is also a typo in it and you probably meant to write "FirstName" instead of "FirdsName".

**Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
  <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="record">
  <record_data>
     <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
     <xsl:for-each select="document('double2.xml')/root/record/policy[./PolicyNumber=current()/PolicyNumber]">
        <xsl:copy-of select="city|street"/>
     </xsl:for-each>
  </record_data>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
 <record_data>
  <PolicyNumber>1</PolicyNumber>
  <FirdsName>aa</FirdsName>
  <LastName>aa</LastName>
  <city>aaCity</city>
  <street>aaStreet</street>
 </record_data>
 <record_data>
  <PolicyNumber>2</PolicyNumber>
  <FirdsName>bb</FirdsName>
  <LastName>bb</LastName>
  <city>bbCity</city>
  <street>bbStreet</street>
 </record_data>
</root>
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like below will work for you.

NOTE : I have not ran this code. where I check `not(policy)` you might do some change in xpath like `not(./policy)`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:for-each select="Root/record">
    <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="not(policy)">
      <record_data>
        <PolicyNumber><xsl:value-of select="PolicyNumber"/></PolicyNumber>
        <FirdsName><xsl:value-of select="FirdsName"/></FirdsName>
        <LastName><xsl:value-of select="LastName"/></LastName>
        <city><xsl:value-of select="city"/></city>
        <street><xsl:value-of select="street"/></street>
      </record_data>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:otherwise>
       <record_data>
        <PolicyNumber><xsl:value-of select="policy/PolicyNumber"/></PolicyNumber>
        <FirdsName><xsl:value-of select="policy/FirdsName"/></FirdsName>
        <LastName><xsl:value-of select="policy/LastName"/></LastName>
        <city><xsl:value-of select="policy/city"/></city>
        <street><xsl:value-of select="policy/street"/></street>
      </record_data>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: This solution does not work. It does not take into consideration the fact that the source is split in two separate XML files.